# Specifying text/string types as value for Hadoop counters

Tags: java, hadoop, cloud, mapreduce

The current methods to set/increment hadoop counters only take in `long` values.

eg: `increment(long incr)` and `setValue(long value)` are two methods I pulled out from the Hadoop Javadocs.

My requirement is to store more complex type of information as part of the counters (as key/value pairs). This info might involve `(string, string)` key,value pairs.

How do I achieve this using Hadoop counters?
If this is not possible, is there any other datastructure/facility in Hadoop/MR that allows storing such misc information that could be retrieved later by specifying the job_id, etc.

Thanks,
Params

Answer (score 1):

Counters work because counts are the sum of the counts. Each task has its own counter which can be aggregated higher up. String don't quite have the same type of information (how do you increment a string?).

Check out [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) for this. It is great for storing miscellaneous information and coordinating between processes. You can create a znode that represents a job run (the job_id perhaps?) and then have individual strings as children.

Comment: 1. Will ZK scale, if there are thousands of MR tasks writing counters/strings? 2. Can objects be stored in ZK instead of strings?

Comment: ZK will scale to thousands ESPECIALLY if you are writing to unique znodes (instead of updating the same one). No, you can only store strings. I usually store serialized objects in there (or JSON), though.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hadoop Counters support only Strings, key/value pairs can be used to collect the statistics using the [OutputCollector.collect(K,V)](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputCollector.html#collect%28K,%20V%29) in the map and reduce functions.

The advantage of this, the statistics from the mapper using the OutputCollector can be further processed (like aggregation) in the reducer function. The statistics from the reducer are just written to the specified output format without any processing.